# how to add editing live website on the website?

Tags: web, live, edit, ipb

if you have ever worked with IPB Forums you will know that you can make changes to your site in the ACP (admin control panel) well what im wanting to do is make something like the one that they use for the "look & feel" part of the forums where you can make changes to the entire website from the one small area i want to add that to my ACP on my main site to make it easier to make changes.

yes i already own a copy of IPB its v3.2.3 if it makes any difference
i appreciate any and all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into adding a "edit in place" function somewhere in your website/forum. Check out:

```
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable
```

As long as you understand super basic mySQL, PHP, and heard of jQuery/know how to add jQuery plugins to your code, then you are set!

Here is their (link provided above's) demo page:

```
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html
```